# How do you find the Modular Inverse of two very big numbers using any of the Boost Multiprecision Library types? (cpp_int, gmp_int etc)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

I need to find the Modular Multiplicative Inverse of two numbers, who data types are any of the ones offered by Boost's Multiprecision library (gmp_int, cpp_int etc). Is there a built in function to do so? If not, can you explain how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Modular multiplicative inverses were added to boost just a few weeks ago. They are not yet in any Boost release (but should be available in 1.70). To use them, you'll need to clone

```
$ git clone https://github.com/boostorg/integer
```

into your Boost tree, or clone all of boost and point your include paths to it:

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost
$ cd boost/libs/integer
$ git checkout develop
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/boostorg/integer/blob/develop/include/boost/integer/mod_inverse.hpp) and the documentation is [here](https://github.com/boostorg/integer/blob/develop/doc/modular_arithmetic/mod_inverse.qbk).